# How to, get/send/provide/(make accessible) data from a database to static jquery files? From express EJS to static Jquery?

Tags: jquery, express, mongoose, frontend, ejs

Youtube link showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BQU2n_GzbI

Github link: https://github.com/phy5prt/MyPersonalWebsite

How do I get data from my backend database, into the jquery at the front end. The context is I want the the jquery to change a section of the html once the user is not looking at it. The jquery measures viewport size and uses this information to generate a number of cards using database data.

I'm teaching myself programming and so started by making a frontend website then I put on it a mongoose ejs express back-end. Therefore I have several static js files in my public folder. Each file relates to one viewscreen and the webpage is 4 view screens in size. Laid out like with first screen you look at bottom left second top left third right middle and the forth is again bottom left but the jquery has changed that sections html while the user was on page 2.

The website can currently provide a json from the backend replacing the website. It can generate cards from a json saved in the front end.

Thank you very very much. I am a novice so if some of my terminology is wrong please let me know. I feel this must be a problem easily solved but maybe I've used the wrong keywords or not understood the solutions well enough to know the right solution for my problem.

Tech Stack: html css jquery bootstrap express bodyparser mongoose

my app.js code

```
app.route("/")
.get(function(req,res){

ProjectCard.find()
.sort({overallProjectRating:-1})
.limit(4)
.exec(function(err,best4Cards){
  res.render("myWebsite", {
    page2BestCard:best4Cards[0]
    ,page3SecondBestCard:best4Cards[1]
    ,page3ThirdBestCard:best4Cards[2]
    ,page3FourthBestCard:best4Cards[3]
```

my pg.4 static jquery code that makes the html works like this

```
 for(var j=0; j<projectCards[arrayLoopInt].technologiesArray.length; j++ ){
          techArrayHtml += cardHtml2 + projectCards[arrayLoopInt].technologiesArray[j].technologyName +
          cardHtml3+projectCards[arrayLoopInt].technologiesArray[j].technologyImagePath+cardHtml4;}
```

projectCards is just a var in another file called dummyData and looks like this var projectCards[{,,,,[{}],[{}],}] using the same name as my mongoose model.

I've read several things to do with ajax and injection and I am hoping I have simply missed something obvious.

I have tried writing ejs into the html that is made by the static js file, but the ejs just showed as writing as it wasnt there when the page was rendered.

I've tried putting ejs around the javascript in the javascript file

I attempted but failed to pass the information from the ejs to the html and have the javascript take it from the the html.

I've tried module export but the static js files seem to have no idea what it is

I tried in the html putting the app.js file as one of its static js files, this didnt work and I imagine if it had would of been very dodgy.

Thanks very very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

So I had been advised to avoid ajax, which was why my research had a blindspot, but it was exactly what i needed.

This is the code I used

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/carousel',
  method: 'GET',
data: {techButton: saughtTechnology},
 success: function (saughtTechnologyProjectCards) {
  // console.log("complete: getSaughtTechnology is returning: " + saughtTechnologyProjectCards.Length + " cards of technology: " + saughtTechnology +  " they look like this " + JSON.stringify(saughtTechnologyProjectCards) + "  " + JSON.stringify(saughtTechnologyProjectCards[0]))
  generateCarouselWithSaughtTechnologyCards(saughtTechnologyProjectCards);

 //data: {query: saughtTechnology}       //this is the bit i need to check if it is right
}})
// .then(function (saughtTechnologyProjectCards) {
//   console.log("then: getSaughtTechnology is returning: " + saughtTechnologyProjectCards.Length + " cards of technology: " + saughtTechnology +  " they look like this " + saughtTechnologyProjectCards + "  " + saughtTechnologyProjectCards[0]);
//   //generateCarouselWithSaughtTechnologyCards(saughtTechnologyProjectCards);
// })
.catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
});

}else{

  $("#carouselTechTitle").text("All "+ "Projects");generateCarouselWithSaughtTechnologyCards();}
}
```

and i havent read it because I've found what I needed but this looks like a good resource if your stuck with the same stack

https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/building-app-from-scratch-with-node-js-mongodb-e00d3179afc1